# Stripe Supscription with asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I want to integrate my application using stripe for payments.I know how to pay with card using stripe,but i want to add customers with a subscription using stripe.can any one help me about stripe subscription.

how to create a controller page and view page for stripe subscription

## view page

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="pk_test_..."
            data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
            data-name="Demo SaaS Site"
            data-description="Pro Subscription ($29 per month)"
            data-panel-label="Subscribe"
            data-label="Subscribe"
            data-amount="2900">
    </script>
```

## controller

```
public ActionResult Charge(string stripeToken, string stripeEmail, string PlanId)
      {
            string apiKey = "sk_test_...";
            var stripeClient = new Stripe.StripeClient(apiKey);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

            dynamic response = stripeClient.CreateCustomer(stripeToken, "USD", stripeEmail);
            var myCustomer = new StripeCustomerCreateOptions();

            // set these properties if it makes you happy
            myCustomer.Email = "mogan777@email.com";
            myCustomer.Description = "welcome";

            myCustomer.PlanId = "1234";

            var customerService = new StripeCustomerService();
            StripeCustomer stripeCustomer = customerService.Create(myCustomer);

            return View("Charge");
        }
```

Comment: What's not working with your code exactly? You seem to have the right approach

Comment: How to add a customer on subscription,?while paying he transaction details displayed in event and logs right.like this how to set a customer select  a plan and subscribe and displayed  details in subscription page

Comment: This code does all that already. I think you want to talk to Stripe support here because you are likely confused on how it works: https://support.stripe.com/email